# UILabel keeps resizing to a height of 0 regardless of the text

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uilabel, constraints

I have a UILabel with the following constraints

[image]

and I set the number of Lines equal to 0. The layout on IB can be seen below. I want this UILabel to expand dynamically based on the text that I receive where the views below it get pushed down based on the height of the UILabel. However, that is not what happens.

[image]

As seen below, the UILabel doesn't appear at all. It seems to have a height of 0 regardless of what I set the text to be. Does anyone know what I need to modify to make this happen? Does anyone know why the UILabel has a height of 0?

[image]

UPDATES:

Things I tried given the comments below.

1. word wrap, nothing changed
2. adding a height constraint on UILabel, text gets cut off after the first line
3. height constraint with greater than or equal to constant, text still gets cut off after the first line

Answer (score 3):

I created a dummy View according to your requirement.

[image]

1. Button has fixed constraints : leading width ,height, top space.
2. For label : leading, trailing, topSpace to button

[image]    [image]

3.For View below the label: give leading, trailing, height , top space to label
[image]

4. so here label height is not fixed .so it will change according to text.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this and it didn't work. The button above has fixed constraints, the UILabel has leading, trailing, and top to button constraints, the UIView below the label has to leading, trailing, fixed height, and top to UILabel. The UILabel has number of lines set to 0 and I set it to word wrap as well. I followed all the steps listed above but it still don't work for me. The text gets cut off after the first line.

Comment: @user2492566 : can u give full image of view controller. Is there any other views below that images

Comment: I updated the screenshot to include everything in the view controller. The are a bunch of other views below the UILabel. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @user2492566 : May be i think problem with constraints of views below UILabel. is that imageviews height is fixed

Comment: the red view has a fixed height but the imageviews below that don't have fixed height. I want them to dynamically expand or contract depending on how much space is left over after the label's height increases

Comment: @user2492566 : try like this..take a new UIView..place all the views below label into this view ..and for this new UIView, give leading,trailing,bottom to 0 and top to label..hope this helps

Comment: @user2492566 : if it works ,upvote and accept the answer and make it helpful for others too..

Answer (score 2):

After setting the text in label try out "labelName.sizeToFit()" this will automatically adjust the height of your label.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set a `height` constraint to your Label.

Comment: I tried this but the text gets cut off after the first line

Comment: So you want your label to resize dynamically regarding the number of line. You can call `sizeToFit` after setting the label

Answer (score 0):

Considering the information you provided, it seems like it doesn't have enough height because you are using bottom constraint to the view under it. Rearrange your constraints or give a height constraint to the UILabel.

Comment: I tried adding a height constraint on the label but that only gets it to display the first line of the text. How do you suggest that I rearrange the constraints?

Comment: if you want multiple lines and auto sizing you shouldn't give the label a height or a bottom constraint. I would suggest creating an empty storyboard and making the label work like you want first by adding leading, trailing and top constraint, check if it's working, then add the other elements without giving your label a height or bottom constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `UILabel`,Set the Line Breaks mode is **Word Wrap** and set the number of lines is **0**, example is given below,

[image]

And set the Height Constraints, If you set height contraints then select the `UILabel`, see the right side, select **show the size Inspector** --> Double click the **height Contraints** --> **Relation** --> set the **Greater Than or Equal**, its automatically expand the label, example is given below,

[image]

hope its helpful

Comment: I just tried this with word wrap, lines equal to 0, and adding a height constraint with greater than or equal to and now only the first line of text is displayed. So it still gets cut off, but I don't understand why since the height is greater than or equal to. So it should expand if there's more text.